# iDangero Swiper using Worklight?

Tags: javascript, android, jquery, ibm-mobilefirst

Is there an easy way to implement this? I am having trouble getting it to work properly. I tried following the instructions on the website to have it load at `window.onload`, but Worklight seems to fire that call before the DOM is even visible, so I couldn't do that. I have some initialization code and so I am calling the following method in that code:

```
function runSwiper(){
    // iDangerous Swiper
    var mySwiper = new Swiper('.swiper-container', {
        pagination : '.pagination',
        loop : true,
        grabCursor : true,
        simulateTouch : true,
        paginationClickable : true
    });
}
```

Yet, all I see in my carousel is just Text. I have two test slides in there currently, but the slide doesn't even seem to work on my Android emulator. Is there anything else I need to be doing for this to work properly? If not, is there something that works as nicely as this that will play nice with Worklight?

I am using worklight version 6.2. I am usingth is: http://www.idangero.us/sliders/swiper/api.php

What I am aiming to do is fade out one div that has information, and fade in another div that has more info and the Swiper present, so initially this swiper will be hidden.

Comment: How about a link? Worklight version? a little bit more background and scenario? a bit fuller code snippet.

Comment: Yup, sorry about that. Added some more info. If you need anything else let me know.

Comment: Tried running this code in wlCommonInit()? Provide your Worklight project (upload a demo project to Dropbox), I'll see if I can get it running tomorrow.

Comment: I did. It is nested in another function being called in the WLCommonInit().

Comment: Worklight doesn't fire window.onload, the browser (webview) does. Does it work if you call it when the window is loaded? Can you call it from a button? will it work? Does it work without Worklight (build a simple HTML, CSS, JavaScript example, put it on a server and access it through the device browser)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I turns out, in my case, the easiest way to call the swiper to initialize was later on (being that it was in a hidden div) instead of at `window.onload`. In addition, I had some issues with slides disappearing, which I fixed by having the slides pre-defined in the HTML instead of adding them dynamically.